# Spring form:options title from String

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags, tld

Pretty simple question. If I have a list of strings, which I render in a dropdown through Springs form:options tag, how do I set the value of the title property to be the strings value?

```
<form:options items="${listOfString}" title=" ?? "/>
```

Alternatively I would do a forEach, but can it be done with a form:options tag?

Thanks!

Comment: So, i'm guessing this can't be done? :)

Comment: Are you saying you want the title to be a concatenation of all the strings in the list?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You just omit the 'title' attribute:

```
<form:options items="${listOfString}"/>
```

Comment: Hmm.. Did you actually mean 'title' property or the options labels?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean that there are the `itemLabel` and `itemValue` params and that you would also like to have an `itemTitle` param so you can specify the field name on the object that contains the string to become a title="" attribute.

So relating to this issue: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7648

If that's the case, I found that I had to roll my own solution. Here's the `.tag` file that I wrote to do it:

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ attribute name="items" type="java.util.Collection" required="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="itemLabel" type="java.lang.String" required="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="itemValue" type="java.lang.String" required="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="itemTitle" type="java.lang.String" required="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="selectedValue" type="java.lang.String" required="true" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach var="entry" items="${items}">
    <c:set var="selectedAttrString" value="${entry[itemValue] == selectedValue ? 'selected=\"selected\"' : ''}" />
    <option value="${entry[itemValue]}" label="${entry[itemLabel]}" title="${entry[itemTitle]}" ${selectedAttrString} />
</c:forEach>
```

I've also included capability to set the selected item. I've left out the htmlEscape and css related params because I didn't require them but you could easily add them if required.

Note: the cool part is that SPeL lets you address a field name using a string (much like Javascript) so if we assume `itemValue = "id"` then `entry[itemValue]` evaluates to `entry.id`. Neat hey?

You can find the code behind the form:options tag here btw: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/OptionsTag.java